# How to calculate $\int e^{Ax^2+Bx}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus

For $A$ and $B$ are real number,
$$
\int e^{Ax^2+Bx}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Please show me how to do it?

P.S. This is what I am working on when I stuck on this calculation.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EF135A5AB1CBABA1!9998&authkey=!AEAgURPN_wr-S3M&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: Your attempt? And it's better to write as $$\int e^{Ax^2 + Bx} \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Complete the square and get an error function. $e^{\pm x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Please be more clearly. I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: $Ax^2 + Bx = A\left( x + \frac{B}{2A} \right)^2 - \frac{B^2}{4A}$, so after a change of variable $y = x + \frac{B}{2A}$ we get an integral of the form that @JackD'Aurizio mentioned.

Comment: Thank guys. You could see my work on the link in the question.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no endpoints in your integral, i.e. are you sure that your integral is indefinite and not definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: it is $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{2 a x+b}{2
   \sqrt{a}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}$$